# Dialog.confirm popup animation bottom to top

Tags: magento-1.9, popup

i am using magento 1.9
i want to change the animation effect for the dialog popup
Please, how to change the FadeIn effect to "Bottom to up slide"

my code :

```
                var win =  Dialog.confirm(
            $('email').innerHTML, {
                className: "popup",
                id: "popupDialog",
                width: popupWidth,
                zIndex: 2001,
            }

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work because I have not tried it but sharing here what I have researched about it--

You need to use parameters `showEffect` and `hideEffect` for animation.

you can check all parameters of `dialog` in this file --

> root_directory/js/prototype/window.js

and you can search for an effect from this file --

> root_directory/js/scriptaculous/effects.js

here you would find effect `Effect.SlideUp`, might be this is what you looking for.

Now above code like like -

```
var win =  Dialog.confirm(
        $('email').innerHTML, {
            className: "popup",
            id: "popupDialog",
            width: popupWidth,
            zIndex: 2001,
            showEffect: // here you can check by use either Element.SlideDown or Effect.SlideDown
            hideEffect: // here you can check by use either Element.SlideDown or Effect.SlideDown
        }
    );
```

This is just an idea, you need to play a bit with above code.

I hope it would help you.

Comment: i tried all that functions : showEffect, showEffectOptions, hideEffect .. no result : S